# Scala batch processing triggered by size or time

Tags: scala

I'd like to batch up some events for processing, and have the triggering of the processing for a batch be based on the number of events reaching a certain threshold OR a time interval expiring (whichever happens first).  What should I consider?  Futures?  Akka?  Some more special-purpose library that might exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

- Using Akka
- Using Quartz

This depends on your specific architecture, but you can use any form of scheduling. You can use an [Akka scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/scheduler.html) to schedule a task to run regularly and use your own internal queue to trigger the batch job if it's full. You can also do very similar things with [Quartz](https://quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set%2Fco-use_jobs_and_triggers.html%23) but you might have to write more boilerplate code with the benefit of having more flexibility.

If you don't wish to bring in a fairly heavyweight library, I suppose you could implement something yourself, but you would be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you, will look at Akka!